# hpacucli on HP ProLiant DL320e Gen8 with Ubuntu 12.04LTS 64bits

Tags: 12.04, drivers, server, hp, raid

I'm trying to get working the HP Smart Array utility "hpacucli" on a ProLiant DL320e Gen8 server since it's [officially certified](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201208-11506/).

The program is installed successfully (I followed [this guide](http://www.randomhacks.co.uk/installing-hp-proliant-support-pack-psp-on-ubuntu-12-04/)) but seems to not recognize the controller:

```
~# hpacucli ctrl all show config

Error: No controllers detected.
```

I tested it with the current 3.8 series kernels and with 3.2.0-23.36 with the same results. I've also tried some other solutions I found googling like execute the program with "uname26" or "setarch".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for your class of hardware  (Gen8)

there is this technote: http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/kb/docDisplay?javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.prp_ba847bafb2a2d782fcbb0710b053ce01=wsrp-navigationalState%3DdocId%253Demr_na-c03742583-1%257CdocLocale%253D%257CcalledBy%253D&javax.portlet.tpst=ba847bafb2a2d782fcbb0710b053ce01&ac.admitted=1385649180186.876444892.492883150

who says  :
*Advisory: HP ProLiant Gen8 Servers - The HP Dynamic Smart Array B120i and B320i Controller Driver for Linux and VMware (hpvsa) Must Be Downloaded from HP.COM in Order to Use RAID Functionality*

Not sure that HP provides drivers for other distribution than RedHat and SuSE.

I suggest to get expert advice from you HP support to validate.

Comment: Thanks, seems that certification [only applies to SATA mode](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu-certification/+question/214703). By now the best solution for me seems to be a software RAID.

Comment: The technote says that RAID is software implemented by the hpva driver (that's why they provide the driver) so no regret to use another software RAID implementation. BTW I was thinking you could create the raid stripe at boot time, but as the technote says RAID is software implemented that would not work... (maybe you could try anyway, just to be sure that the technote is true)